# Tips for saying "Banana Bread" inconspicuously

Tags: spyparty

As a spy in [SpyParty](http://www.spyparty.com/), I'm having a hard time contacting the Double Agent: it seems as soon as the sniper hears the words, he/she starts highighting everyone who is in a conversation and lowlighting the others, which makes the following of the game harder for the spy.

What are some basic tips for saying "Banana Bread" inconspicuously?

Comment: Plantain pastry? Not exactly a pastry, but you get the idea.

Comment: One method might be to save the banana bread for the last, so it won't *matter* who he highlights for future investigation at that point. Another would be to hold off on saying it until there are as many people in conversations as possible to make him work for it.

Comment: Thanks for the pieces of advice. Please do not answer in the section for comments, so we can vote.

Comment: As I don't know how this game works, the question and the comments are extremely amusing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I recommend contacting the Double Agent (a.k.a. DA) under 3 situations:

1. Do it first, before the Sniper has a chance to get her bearings.
2. Do it last, so the Sniper's desire for "bookkeeping" keeps it occupied during the 10-second countdown to victory.
3. Do it when every single person is in a conversation.  Difficult on Ballroom, easy on Balcony, nearly impossible on Veranda, and difficult on Courtyard.

The third item is a good piece of advice whenever you want to do a Banana Bread (BB), but it is separate because sometimes an opportunity opens up which is too good to pass up, like if the DA walks up to you while you are in a conversation **and** everyone is in a conversation. If you note that the Sniper is doing this often, then try to do a perfect "fake BB", and walk away immediately after doing it so you get low-lighted.